# Jakarta Mail unresponsive

Tags: jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send mail using Jakarta Mail 2.0.0, but the application ends up 'frozen', with no messages what so ever. This happens when the SocketFetcher class tries to instansiate the static 'MailLogger' member. I have downloaded and compiled the Jaf 2.0.0 source files.

Has anyone seen this?

Android Studio 4.1.1 with OpenJdk 11.0.2 on Windows

Ove

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Turned out to be missing configuratiom of the smtp protocol.
Ove

Comment: can you share your solution, please